# PHP Class Function List in Comments

Tags: php, class, function

Whenever I write a class in PHP, I like to put a list of public functions at the top of the class like this:

```
// add_project($apikey, $post, $email)
// create_user($apikey, $email, $firstname, $lastname, $rolename, $pid)     
// user_join_project($apikey, $email, $pid)
```

I was wondering if there were any tools that can automate this process. Like perhaps I could load the class file and it could generate a list of the function names, variables and such?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you just want a list of the members you've defined, why not use an IDE that presents the information to you directly?

Comment: I use Coda, it doesn't have that ability,

Comment: phpDesigner (and many others) have that ability.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to look into this, it looks like phpDesigner and PHP Storm are both trial versions, are there any good ones that are free?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [phpDocumentor](http://phpdoc.org). You use DocBlock syntax for comments (similar to Javadoc and in other languages) then pass your PHP source files through the phpDocumentor parser, and it generates API documentation for you.

A rough example:

```
/**
 * Adds a project.
 * 
 * @param string $apikey The API key.
 * @param object $post The post.
 * @param string $email A supplied email address.
 * @return void
 */
function add_project($apikey, $post, $email) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a not great deal of value in this approach.

First off, if you're not already doing so you should mark each of your methods (and indeed member variables) with the [appropriate visibility](http://php.net/manual/kr/language.oop5.visibility.php) (public/protected/private). You could then use a solution such as [phpDoc](http://phpdoc.org/), which to properly document each method argument in addition to providing an overall purpose for each method/class, etc.

You can then automatically generate documentation for your project in HTML format (amongst others).

Answer (score 0):

There are various tools for this. They are called PHP documentor's. I use an IDE called PHPStorm that has a documentor integrated.

[Here is some more information on PHPDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done pretty easily with [Parsekit](http://php.net/parsekit).

Using this ("tmp.php") as sample data:

```
<?php
class Fruit
{
    public function apple($cored) {}
    public function orange($peeled) {}
    public function grape($colour, $seedless) {}
}
```

Here's a simple Parsekit example to dump a class's functions:

```
<?php
$parsed = parsekit_compile_file($argv[1]);
foreach ($parsed['class_table'] as $class => $classdat) {
    foreach ($classdat['function_table'] as $func => $funcdat) {
        echo "{$class}::{$func}(";
        $first = true;
        foreach ($funcdat['arg_info'] as $arg => $argdat) {
            if (!$first) {
                echo ', ';
            }
            echo "\${$argdat['name']}";
            $first = false;
        }
        echo ")\n";
    }
}
```

…and here it is in use:

```
$ php parse.php tmp.php
Fruit::grape($colour, $seedless)
Fruit::orange($peeled)
Fruit::apple($cored)
```